# Add hline with population median for each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, median

I'd like to plot a horizontal facet-wide line with the population median of that facet.

I tried the approach without creating a dummy summary table with the following code:

```
require(ggplot2)

dt = data.frame(gr = rep(1:2, each = 500),
            id = rep(1:5, 2, each = 100), 
            y = c(rnorm(500, mean = 0, sd = 1), rnorm(500, mean = 1, sd = 2)))


ggplot(dt, aes(x = as.factor(id), y = y)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ gr) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = median(y), group = gr), colour = 'red')
```

However, the line is drawn for the median of the entire dataset instead of the median separately for each facet:
[image]

In the past, a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244157/ggplot2-add-line-for-average-per-group) has been suggested to use

```
  geom_line(stat = "hline", yintercept = "median")
```

but it's been discontinued (produces the error "No stat called StatHline").

Another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759193/error-no-stat-called-stathline) suggested

```
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=..y.., ymin=..y.., y = mean))
```

but it generates

```
Error in data.frame(y = function (x, ...)  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1000
```

Finally, there's a way to plot the median by creating a [dummy table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187287/ggplot2-add-geom-line-for-each-facet-in-bland-altman-plot) with the desired stats but I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to add a new column with the computed median, you can add a `geom_smooth` using a quantile regression :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(quantreg)

set.seed(1234)

dt <- data.frame(gr = rep(1:2, each = 500),
                id = rep(1:5, 2, each = 100), 
                y = c(rnorm(500, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                      rnorm(500, mean = 1, sd = 2)))

ggplot(dt, aes(y = y)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = as.factor(id))) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = id), method = "rq", formula = y ~ 1, se = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ gr)
```

[image: boxplot and median]

Answer (score 23):

You could create an extra column in `dt` for median per facet.

```
library(dplyr) # With dplyr for example
dt <- dt %>% group_by(gr) %>%
  mutate(med = median(y))

# Rerun ggplot line with yintercept = med
ggplot(dt, aes(x = as.factor(id), y = y)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ gr) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = med, group = gr), colour = 'red')
```

[image]