# ggplot2 boxplots - How to group factors levels on the x-axis (and add reference lines for each group mean)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, forcats

I have 30 plant species for which I have displayed the distributions of midday leaf water potential (`lwp_md`) using boxplots and the package `ggplot2`. But how do I group these species along the x-axis according to their leaf habits (e.g. `Deciduous`, `Evergreen`) as well as display a reference line indicating the mean `lwp_md` value for each leaf habit level?

I have attempted with the package `forcats` but really have no idea how to proceed with this one. I can't find anything after an extensive search online. The best I seem able to do is order species by some other function e.g. the median.

Below is an example of my code so far. Note I have used the packages `ggplot2` and `ggthemes`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(zz, aes(x=fct_reorder(species, lwp_md, fun=median, .desc=T), y=lwp_md)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=leaf_habit)) +
  theme_few(base_size=14) +
  theme(legend.position="top", 
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=8, angle=45, vjust=1, hjust =1)) +
  xlab("Species") +
  ylab("Maximum leaf water potential (MPa)") +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Leaf habit",
                      breaks=c("DEC", "EG"),
                      labels=c("Deciduous", "Evergreen"))
```

Here's a subset of my data including 4 of my species (2 deciduous, 2 evergreen):

```
> dput(zz)
structure(list(id = 1:20, species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
), .Label = c("AMYELE", "BURSIM", "CASXYL", "COLARB"), class = "factor"), 
    leaf_habit = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("DEC", 
    "EG"), class = "factor"), lwp_md = c(-2.1, -2.5, -2.35, -2.6, 
    -2.45, -1.7, -1.55, -1.4, -1.55, -0.6, -2.6, -3.6, -2.9, 
    -3.1, -3.3, -2, -1.8, -2, -4.9, -5.35)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

An example of how I'm looking to display my data, cut and edited - I would like `species` on x-axis, `lwp_md` on y-axis:
[image]

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35701663/8449629) suit your needs? (replacing median with mean)

Comment: Yes I was specifically looking to display the mean. Probably should have edited my code to indicate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gpplot` defaults to ordering your factors alphabetically. To avoid this you have to supply them as ordered factors. This can be done by arranging the `data.frame` and then redeclaring the factors. To generate the mean value we can use `group_by` and mutate a new mean column in the df, that can later be plotted.

Here is the complete code:

```
library(ggplot)
library(ggthemes)
library(dplyr)

zz2 <- zz %>% arrange(leaf_habit) %>%  group_by(leaf_habit) %>% mutate(mean=mean(lwp_md))
zz2$species <- factor(zz2$species,levels=unique(zz2$species))

ggplot(zz2, aes(x=species, y=lwp_md)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=leaf_habit)) +
  theme_few(base_size=14) +
  theme(legend.position="top", 
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=8, angle=45, vjust=1, hjust =1)) +
  xlab("Species") +
  ylab("Maximum leaf water potential (MPa)") +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Leaf habit",
                      breaks=c("DEC", "EG"),
                      labels=c("Deciduous", "Evergreen")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(species, ymax = mean, ymin = mean),
                size=0.5, linetype = "longdash", inherit.aes = F, width = 1)
```

Comment: Brilliant, it worked great! Your explanation was really clear and easy to learn from too. Thank you very much for your time Julian_Hn.

Comment: If this helped you, please consider accepting the answer, so that others can learn from it too.